# Is it possible to smoke a McDonald's french fry like a cigarette?

Tags: nutrition

This [Facebook video](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10154524853115457) purports to show Trevor Ferrell light the end of a french fry, bite off the other end, and inhale smoke through the fry like a cigarette.

He goes on to suggest that this is evidence that the food is not healthful.

Is this possible? Does the video show a realistic situation? Does this mean the food is not healthful.

Comment: What's really being claimed here?  That you can put a fry in your mouth, light the other end, and inhale?  Surely that's obviously true of any object that's somewhat flammable and porous.

Comment: @Nate: Wasn't obvious to me. Before watching the video, I would have thought it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: I'm unhappy about there being two very different questions here. A relatively simple one about feasibility of the act shown (e.g. what Nate is responding to) and the rather more difficult one about whether "smokability" implies "bad to eat" - which I suspect is going to be hard to answer well.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Actually, I'd bet that lots of healthy foods are smokable.  (This of course could raise a "no true Scotsman" problem - if it's smokable, maybe it's not as healthy as you thought!)

Comment: Maybe i should edit out the easier question? I had it there as an introduction... And are normal foods really smokable? I do not know much about this but the red glow is surely caused by something more than just suction?

Comment: I've closed it while we sort out what it should say, and then we can re-open it. I listened again the Ferrell's commentary, and he doesn't make much of a direct claim. He clearly wants people to avoid eating french fries, and he thinks the food is tampered with, but I didn't hear any actual statements that we could get our teeth into. He never says anything like "All smokable foods are bad to eat". "McDonald's fries are unhealthful" is probably the closest to his general claim, which has nothing to do with the demonstration, but could be addressed here.

Comment: @Oddthinking You are right, but I think the connection between the smokability (OK, this isn't a real word) and harmfulness is strongly implied, which is why he smokes it in the first place.